# Programmatically find all tiles within certain distance with obstacles in the way

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for a better way to create an array of points that are a certain distance away from the starting point. There may be obstacles in the way, which would be impassable.

```
x x x o x x x x
x x o o o x x x
x o o o o o x x
o o o A o o o x
x o B B o o x x
x x x x o x x x
x x x x x x x x
```

x - empty // A - start // B - obstacles // o - distance >= 3

So my current implementation uses recursion and basically searches in every direction until its reached a distance of 3. It looks something like this:

```
- (NSArray *) findTiles:(CGPoint)position for:(int)area;
{
    // Holding array
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    CGPoint p = ccp(position.x - 1, position.y);
    if ( [self isValidTile:p] && area != 0 )
        if ( ![self isOccupiedTile:p] )
            [array addObjectsFromArray: [self findMoveTiles:p for:area - 1]];

    p = ccp(position.x, position.y - 1);
    if ( [self isValidTile:p] && area != 0 )
        if ( ![self isOccupiedTile:p] )
            [array addObjectsFromArray: [self findMoveTiles:p for:area - 1]];

    p = ccp(position.x + 1, position.y);
    if ( [self isValidTile:p] && area != 0 )
        if ( ![self isOccupiedTile:p] )
            [array addObjectsFromArray: [self findMoveTiles:p for:area - 1]];

    p = ccp(position.x, position.y + 1);
    if ( [self isValidTile:p] && area != 0 )
        if ( ![self isOccupiedTile:p] )
            [array addObjectsFromArray: [self findMoveTiles:p for:area - 1]];

    // Add ourself only if we are empty
    if ( [self isValidTile:position] && ![self isOccupiedTile:position])
        if ( ![array containsObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:position]] )
            [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:position]];

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```

Does anyone have a faster way to do it? This works fine, but gets incredibly slow with big areas. Also the returned array have many repeated coordinates as containsObject: doesn't seem to work.

PS - not sure if graph algorithm applies here (I'd say it does)

Comment: I might misunderstand the problem but are you given the start point? If all you need is to find  all points within certain distance from the start, you already know the range right? If start(x, y) and if within distance d, you know you will check at most 2d * 2d number of tiles (should be less than this) ? Then the next thing is to check out of these points which are obstacles. Once you have the obstacles, you should be able to mathematically eliminate the tiles that was blocked in our original set (2d* 2d)

Comment: @grc how would you eliminate the tiles that got blocked? I understand that I can just take out the tiles that are occupied from the list of tiles within a distance D away from the start. But how do you find all those points that can no longer be reached within D steps due to the obstacles?

Comment: I think this will depend on how the rules set up by the problem. From what I see in the graph, if 'start=(x, y)' and 'obstacle=(x-1, y)' for example. Then you know obstacle (to the left of start) blocks all the tiles that are to the left of itself with the same y. So '(x-2, y) (x-3, y) ... (x-d, y)' are all blocked There might be more to the problem that I did not know. Same logic can be applied to if obstacle is in other direction.

Comment: I guess maybe states a little bit more about what these tiles are, you do you decide if one tile is blocked by an obstacle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after coming back to this after a while,

I realized a normal BFS doesn't actually work because there is no way to tell how far you've travelled from the root node.

I implemented a BFS with a stack instead, so its similar to a dfs

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a solution. not sure though

```
**Quadrant**


       |
   II  |    I
       |
-------A---------
       |
  III  |   IV
       |


       |
   II  |
       |
-------A

**Rotate right**
|
|    II
|
A---------

**Rotate right**
A---------
|
|   II
|
```

1. write a logic for finding the route in 4th quadrant with `A` as the center of the Quadrants.
2. write logic to split your array of points into 4 quadrants with `A` as the center ie (0,0). Make sure no axis lines are present in 2 quadrants. So once side of the quarant will have to be placed with an array of blocks.
3. pass each quadrant to the `logic 1` for processing and finding the array of route lengths. Make sure you rotate your matrix will the origin point reaches at the top left corner.
4. depending on the quadrant you could calculate the direction.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typical application of [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). I don't know objective-C, but, you mentioned recursion, which is typically [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). A typical implementation of BFS uses a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29).

You can have a flag on each cell, which you set as soon as you visit it and don't visit the cell again if the flag is set. This would prevent any duplication of cells.

The visited flag wouldn't prevent finding all cells, since BFS is guaranteed to find the shortest path to any cell, since it first visits all cells distance 1, then distance 2, then distance 3, etc. from the start, thus it will always find a shorter path to a cell before a longer path. This is opposed to DFS (using a visited flag), which searches as long paths as possible first, thus it can mark a cell as visited on a length 3 path, even if a length 2 path exists, thus skipping unvisited cells it can get to from that cell.

Comment: So I did think about BFS/DFS when I implemented this. Correct me if I'm wrong, BFS has worst case O(|V+E|) and in my case it would be O(|V+4V|) (4 edges per vertice). My implementation uses recursion and has O(D^4) where D is the furthest distance I want to look. I understand that O(5V) << O(D^4), but is there any faster methods that I can look into?

Comment: Think about it this way - the complexity of BFS is O(M) where M is the number of nodes returned (constant factors don't matter in asymptotic complexity - O(5M) = O(M)). In terms of asymptotic complexity, you can't do better than that (it's impossible to do less work than the output size). It may be possible to derive some BFS which is *slightly* better (by intelligently avoiding checking certain already-explored cells), but it's likely more effort than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I'll go with a BFS method then